# How to change locale in aurelia-froala-editor?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How to change language of **froala-editor** using **aurelia**? Where do I exactly need to add scripts of language files?

Have already checked https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/languages
but I cannot figure out how to add these script files in aurelia.

Comment: https://github.com/froala/aurelia-froala-editor/issues/49#event-2203029583

Answer (score 2):

just import the language that you need, the languages are located in froala-editor/js/languages folder.

```
import 'froala-editor';
import 'froala-editor/js/languages/fr';
```

then define the language:

```
$('.editor').froalaEditor({
  language: 'fr'
});
```